# Is it possible to set up a private server for both PC and Console in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4, server-administration

We are a group of friends (about 10 or so). Some of us own Battlefield 4 on PC, some on Xbox, and some on PS3/4.

On official servers we can't play together (since consoles have a bit of autoaim).

We were thinking to get a private server so we could play together, but can't seem to find any information if you can configure private server to allow both pc and consoles.

Does anyone know if that is possible?

Comment: Without researching anything I'm just gonna say: probably not. Also, what makes you think auto-aim on consoles has anything to do with the server you are connecting to? It really doesn't. If you want to play a game cross-platform, the game client needs to support it. Otherwise there is just no way it will ever work without really intense modding.

Comment: Because they declared it :). Found a post were it was stated that servers are different because console game includes code for auto-aim. It may or may not be the only reason... that part I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this (well, you might try coding it to support both platforms, but it would take months (speculation) to do). The fact that all the platforms can't play together is mainly caused by console vendors. You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Console_exclusivity).

Comment: If it was caused by console vendors, please explain why windows PC is not compatible with Xbox?

Comment: @Timelord64 Microsoft doesn't earn as money games sold on pc, but SOME games are already playable multiplatform between pc and Xbox though (those are bought from Windows/Xbox Store). [See here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/windows-10) "PC vs. Xbox One multiplayer"

Comment: The amount of games that work across platform greatly undermine the amount that don't. This was also not the first attempt; A similar venture on the Xbox 360 failed miserably.

Comment: Also, your reference is a topic on games being released exclusively for one console, and has nothing to do with cross-platform. Perhaps you mis-linked?

Comment: Console exclusivity means the game was only released on **one** console. It was "exclusive to that console". This is also what your article states. It has nothing to do with cross-platform; In fact, the only relation is no relation. It would never be possibly to cross platform a "console exclusive", because it would not be available on the other console.